# Create view with except condition

Tags: sql, oracle

Example i want to create a view name TEST

which i already created a view before that
View name : customer

Inside customer View:

```
//CUSTOMER
NAME      ID            ADDRESS       AGE     SEX      TELNO     EMAIL
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
CHRIS     1               12321312     21      F        646885   ascs@gmail
JOHN      2               SADASDSA     23      M        5452131  asd@gmail
MAY       3               LKJLKJLKJ    32      F        645643   cxz@gmail
```

So i want to create a view name TEST that will store all column inside CUSTOMER but EXCEPT TELNO EMAIL.

so i used this query:

```
CREATE VIEW TEST AS
  SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER
  EXCEPT
  SELECT TELNO,EMAIL FROM CUSTOMER;
```

But i fail to work, got errors come out. SQL command not properly end and point to EXCEPT, what's wrong?

Comment: Didn't you just post this, and get an answer to your question? The answer doesn't change because you've deleted the previous question and reposted. (Also if you do this continually you'll be automatically banned by the system - deleted posts are taken into account so please be careful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to list all the columns that you want explicitly:

```
CREATE VIEW TEST AS
    SELECT NAME, ID, ADDRESS, AGE, SEX
    FROM CUSTOMER;
```

There is no way to exclude some columns from a `*` list.

`EXCEPT` is an operator in SQL Server.  The equivalent in Oracle is `MINUS`.  However, this works at the row level, not at the column level.

If you want to get all the columns in the table, except for those two, you can use `all_tab_columns`:

```
select column_name
from all_tab_columns
where lower(table_name) = 'customer' and
      lower(column_name) not in ('telno', 'email');
```

You can then paste them into the `select` clause.

Comment: when i follow the second 1. the result return no rows selected

Comment: that is view , not a table.

Comment: @user3553846 . . . Just put `create view . . .` before the `select`.

Comment: i can't get what you mean

Comment: created but no rows selected as i mention